# In Yii2 Kartik Select2 widget how to make an ajax call on select event?

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

In select2 widget of yii2, how can we make an ajax call from the widget to a function in our controller:
Scenario is I need to create a custom ID for a table the id depends upon the two dropdown value and on select event of the select2 drop down I need to fetch the record and construct the ID and put the value of the newly created id in the form filed.
I just have problem in making an ajax call from the select2 dropdown widget

Comment: <?=
 $form->field($model, 'ComplexDetails_complexdetailsId')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
 'language' => 'de',
 'data' => $data_complex,//[1 => "First", 2 => "Second", 3 => "Third", 4 => "Fourth", 5 => "Fifth"],
 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Complex ...'],
 'pluginOptions' => [
  'allowClear' => true,
 ],
'pluginEvents' => [
"select2:select" => "function()
 { 
   document.getElementById('a').value=this.value
 
 }",
 ], 
 ]);
   
 ?>

Answer (score 6):

Try following:

You can use `select2:select` event to make ajax call.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'state_1')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
       "select2:select" => "function() { // function to make ajax call here }",
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'pluginEvents' => [
                   'change' => 'function() {
                        var selectedIds = $(this).val();
                        $.pjax.reload({container: "#testing", data:{tags:selectedIds}});
                    }'
```